# Amplify/Cognito oauth federated sign-in (Google) ,does not show popup, instead redirects in the same page

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

We are using Cognito with Google as the identity provider.

On the client side, we are using Amplify to sign-in sign-out etc.

During the sign in, I call the Amplify federatedSignIn method with the provider as 'Google'"

Something like this:

```
Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: "Google" });
```

This redirects to the google email picker page (oauth).
I was expecting a popup instead of redirecting in the same page.

Is this a client configuration problem in Google Cloud Platform? How would I be able to get a popup instead of redirecting in the same page?

Something to note: This happens on the Hosted UI too.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes - I had to write a script to manually open a new window. Basically, the auth happens in a particular React Route. I just opened this URL as a new browser window.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few things can go wrong here :

1/ You may have to clear cache and hard reload to try it again

2/ Authorised JavaScript origins URL need to be corrected like

```
https://frei.dswswc5n7bb6c.amplifyapp.com
```

and

```
http://localhost:3000
```

3/ Authorised redirect URIs also need to be corrected

```
https://{your-domain-name}.auth.{your-aws-region}.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse
```

4/ You have to make sure both User Pool and Identity Pool are configured correctly using the credentials above